# Point in Polytope?

Tags: linear-programming, computational-geometry, polytopes, convex-hulls, decision-problems

<sup>**Context:** This question is somewhat identical to [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/142418) on MathOverflow, it’s different in that it only focuses on the formula of the solution to the underlying problem.</sup>

---

Suppose I have a convex hull $H$ from the $\mathbb{R}^n$ vertices of a polytope. What is the formula to determine whether a point $p$ is contained within the polytope (convex hull $H$)?

Comment: Your question amounts to find a description of your polytope under the form $AX \le B$ with the test $Ap \stackrel{\large{<}}{\ge} B$.

Comment: Hi @JeanMarie, Your comment wasn’t in english :) and its definitely beyond me at this current point in time. The polytope being in the question is just for context sake, I am only interested in a general formula for finding out if a point $p$ exists within some convex hull $H$

Comment: Please correct my sentence. I will be happy to improve my english. Besides, description of a polytope by a matrix-vector inequality (gathering a set of linear inequalities) $AX \le B$ is completely standard : sooner or later, you will need it in this kind of issues.

Comment: @JeanMarie was just pulling your legs in the sense that the comment was beyond my understanding :)… nothing obviously wrong with the english

Comment: You may want to take a look at chapter 5 of [Kroening & Strichman](https://www.decision-procedures.org).

Answer (score 3):

Assume the vertices that span the convex hull are $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_k\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with coordinates $$
v_i = (v_{i1},v_{i2},\dots,v_{in}).
$$

A point $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$ lies in the convex hull if and only if there exists $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k\geq 0$ with $\sum \lambda_j = 1$ satisfying $$
\sum_{j=1}^k \lambda_j v_j = p.
$$

Let $V$ be the $n\times k$ matrix with columns $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_k$, so the above equation can be written as $$
V\lambda = p
$$ where $\lambda$ denotes the (column) vector $(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k)$. Add the row $(1,1,\dots,1)$ to $V$ to get the matrix $V'$, so $V'$ has the form $$
V' = \begin{bmatrix}
v_{11} & v_{21} & \dots & v_{k1}\\
v_{12} &\ddots & &\vdots \\
\vdots & &\ddots &\vdots \\
v_{1n} & & & v_{kn}\\
1 & 1 & \dots & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Then, $p$ is in the convex hull if and only if there exists a $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^k$ satisfying $$
V'\lambda=\begin{bmatrix}
p\\
1
\end{bmatrix},\qquad\text{and}\qquad \lambda\geq 0.
$$ This is a linear program and you can check if it is feasible using linear programming algorithms.

Comment: Hi @Levent, from this $
\sum_{j=1}^k \lambda_j v_j = p.
$ what’s $\lambda_j$ equal to exactly, I mean how does one come about the values of $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k$?

Comment: @LiNKeR - for underdetermined problem please see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715807/finding-nonnegative-solutions-to-an-underdetermined-linear-system

Comment: @LiNKeR - for overdetermined problem - another way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-negative_least_squares

Comment: @HEKTO thanks, though I still could not find a way to express $\lambda$ explicitly after going through everything (I am no mathematician). I plan on implementing this answer programmatically by considering that a point $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$ existing within a convex hull $H$, according to this always meets the following conditions:

Comment: (a) each $\lambda$ would be $\geq0$ i.e. $(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k)\geq 0$ (b) all $\lambda$s would sum up to be equal to one i.e. $\sum \lambda_j = 1$ (c) and then the sum of the product of vertices and lambda from the convex hull $H$ would equal the point $p$ i.e. $$
\sum_{j=1}^k \lambda_j v_j = p.
$$

Comment: You basically need to run an algorithm for linear programming feasibility for the linear program I described. As far as I know, there is no simple formula to see if $p$ is in the convex hull other than this method. There are many libraries in many programming languages for linear programming.